# "Windows need to restart to continue" during installation ending up in select boot device screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd, windows-installation

After my ssd with the os died on my pc, I got a new one and I'm having issues installing win10.

I used the windows media creation tool to get a boot usb, and at first it was telling me "The selected disk is of the GPT partition style in Windows, This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu."

So after looking around I converted the SSD in to MBR, disabled CSM in the boot options, run the boot usb with UEFI and was able to create partitions and install the media on to the SSD.

But after the initial process was finished, it tells me Windows needs to restart to continue, and because CSM was off it didnt have my SSD in the boot list and would return to the same installation widget. So I removed the usb, enable CSM again and set the SSD as my boot drive, but now it puts me to the reboot and select proper boot device screen.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, please note down the Windows requirements. UEFI mode requires GPT and BIOS/CSM/Legacy requires MBR. So, everything was fine except the part where you booted the installer in Legacy mode.

Comment: CSM in Boot Options does not interfere with a Windows 10 install to a GPT drive in UEFI on multiple systems I work with. Suggest you try  turning CSM back on in your BIOS/Firmware.